# How to style element to fill page width, regardless of containing element's styles?

Tags: css, responsive-design

How can I style an element to fill the page (or body) width, even when the containing element(s) have margins/paddings and relative positioning?

In other words, [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szal/fg9T4/13/), without changing the container or subcontainer, how can I style my blue content div so that its text fills the page width?

I feel like `position: absolute` is close, but no cigar: I want positioning relative to the entire page (or body) width, not relative to a parent element.  Any ideas?

Comment: Will the page or web app ever have vertical scrolling? If it will fit in the window without vertical scrolling then you could use `position: fixed;`. But if the web page or application scrolls vertically then fixed will not work.

Comment: Yes, it will have vertical scrolling. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Are you opposed to using jQuery? I honestly don't think you can achieve this with pure CSS. At least with the current DOM structure.

Comment: Sure.  Obviously, CSS-only would be best, but I would use some kind of script if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible with pure CSS. (*at least with your current HTML structure*)

**However, I propose this jQuery solution:**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    setContentWidth();
});


function setContentWidth()
{
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var leftOffset = $('.container')[0].offsetLeft;

    $('.content').css({'width': windowWidth, 'left': -leftOffset});
}

setContentWidth();
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/fg9T4/16/